# Integral of $\cos(x+2y+3z)$ over a sphere of radius $1$, centered at the origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Need to calculate the following triple integral: $\cos(x+2y+3z)$ over a region $D$, where $D=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2 \le1\}$.

The solid $D$ suggests that I should try using spherical coordinates but then I am not able to simplify the function itself.

This is a question from one of my second year multivariable calculus assignments.

So far I have tried using spherical coordinates and using the trigonometric identities.

Any other approach that I could try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can get $\le$ using `\le`.

Comment: You may exploit the spherical symmetry by using a rotation, so that replacing the integrand by $\cos(hz)$, where $h = \vert(1,2,3)\vert$. Then, you can integrate in slices perpendicular to the $z$-axis.

Comment: @user90189 Sorry but why exactly can you do that? How do you perform the rotation so that the expression in the cosine ends up with just one variable?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by  user90189,

$$\int_D\cos(x+2y+3z)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_D\cos(\sqrt{14}z)\,dx\,dy\,dz.$$

In cylindrical coordinates,

$$2\pi\int_{r=0}^1\int_{z=-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\cos(\sqrt{14}z)\,dz\,r\,dr.$$